# Logging the versions of gradle dependencies used when building for reuse

Tags: gradle

I want to log out the versions of all dependencies for a gradle build to a file, so I can use that file to substitute all dependencies of all modules, so I can rebuild the exact same build later.

It's not possible to manage the dependency tree produced via version control in order to meet some legacy requirements, and given its complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
configurations {
  compile.resolutionStrategy {
    eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
       String group = details.requested.group;
       String name = details.requested.name;
       String version = details.requested.version;
       // log
    }        
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To log the versions the solution Adam provided is the way to go. Alternatively you might be interested in the [`nebula dependency-lock`](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/nebula.dependency-lock) plugin. This is a thirdparty plugin that allows you to use dynamic versions during dev time and lock it down for reproducable builds when you do a release.

cheers,
René

Comment: Thanks for the link. How does the plugin manage which versions those are, without serializing and recording that somewhere? Surely you want visibility of that? My use case has to work in conjunction with another build system and serialization format, so it's unlikely that this plugin will be the approach.

Comment: it does serialize the version as far as I know. I think they use json, but I'm not completely sure.